How do I complete my goals or projects?
I’ve noticed that while I consistently complete client projects with dedication and within deadlines, some of my personal projects tend to remain unfinished, even when I have the time to work on them. The accountability and responsibility of delivering for a client motivate me to stay focused and productive. However, in personal projects, the lack of external accountability sometimes makes it challenging to maintain the same momentum

I can only sympathize with you. It takes enormous mental effort to keep focus over long period of time without compensation. There are certain techniques that people claim that work, but nothing worked for me. And I still haven't finished most of my personal projects.

Our community usually does not give personal coaching advice, it is just another form of educational advice, for which we have a predefined close reason.

... still, for what it is worth: most of your personal "projects" are probably not "projects", I guess they are long-living products, hence open-ended. You can make projects from that by defining versions of those products with clear goals for each version, each one in a working state, and put every "unfinished idea" into a "bucket list" (a.k.a. "backlog"). Make sure whenever you stop working on one of those produicts, you leave it behind in a defined state, a working version. That should at least psychologically help you to avoid the feeling of never getting to an end.

quit your day job and have your personal project as your only source of income

@Ewan yeah, if you have few millions saved on your account. Otherwise literally noone achieved success like that. And even with those millions saved, if you can't focus it won't help you. A straightforward way to end up on streets.

@freakish there are a number of examples of people quitting job to pursue their project and succeeded with millions afterwards.  Most of them had wealthy parents.  A few of them really were at financial risks.  There is however no story of a personal project becoming a big commercial success, just as a side project of someone who continued to work on a daily job.  That's the usual correlation between risk and reward - And nobody can be blamed because chasing the low risk low reward path ;-)

I can sympatize as well ! The fundamental question is: what do these personal project mean for you? Apparently your brain categorised them as less important.  And honestly,  working hard all the year requires a lot of energy and free time with a free mind is sometime needed to recharge. And if it is the challenge with the peers or customers who make you perform best, maybe it's time to give your project a bigger perspective than a solo side-project, involving at least someone else ? Or fix you a deadline after which you will stop if your MVP is not achieved.

@Christophe I hate this kind of argument, because it is extremely biased. Yes, there were people that were successful in doing that. While 99% failed miserably, without any significant contribution and are totally forgotten. I agree though: huge success is highly correlated with huge financial support, that's how it is.

@Christophe also, there were few successful projects that started as a side project, e.g. Twitter, Tumblr. Even Google (side project to PhD, but still). Probably many more, that's the first few that came to my mind.

@freakish the point is to create the responsibilities that make you work at work. ie you wont be paid if you don't, rather than just having a hobby you can no bother with if you don't feel like it. You could also get a partner or an investor involved, so you have responsibilities to them. But might be hard if you can't put the time in yourself

@Ewan throwing yourself into "all or nothing" situation most of the time ends badly. Sorry, but that's not how you build up discipline and responsibilities. You can do that as a side project. And then in case of failure at least you have something.

When you're doing a side project where you are the client you can find discipline simply by respecting yourself as a client.

Right, right. You can just convince yourself. Why no one ever thought about that. XD

@freakish I'm not saying bet the house on every idea you have, but I do think it's something you have to think about seriously. Are you doing this for money? Why does it matter if you don't finish? etc etc
